# Java scanning file and printing word (with multiple instances) once

Tags: java, file, printing

I have a program which scans through a file containing football scores such as:

```
Leeds : 1 : Manchester City : 2
Manchester City : 3 : Chelsea : 1
```

I am currently scanning it by lines and then splitting it up via the :. However I want to create a print out of a team without repeating it
    i.e.

```
Manchester City total goals = 5
Chelsea total goals = 1
Leeds City total goals = 1
```

is there a way I can I can do this without hard coding what the teamname is. so it just scans through a file and selects the teams but only once. The scores are not important here Im just using them as an example the teamnames are what I want to to distinctly print.

I tried:

```
    While (file.hasNext()){
    String line = file.nextLine();
    String[] word = line.split(":");
    System.out.println(teamname+" total goals ="+goals );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing the goals immediately store them in a Map:

```
private Map<String, Integer> goalCounts = new HashMap<>();

private void addGoals(String teamName, int numGoals) {
    if (goalCounts.containsKey(teamName)) {
        goalCounts.put(teamName, goalCounts.get(teamName) + numGoals);
    }
    else {
        goalCounts.put(teamName, numGoals);
    }
}
```

To print out the totals:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> teamGoalsEntry : goalCounts.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(teamGoalsEntry.getKey() + " total goals=" + teamGoalsEntry.getValue());
}
```

You could alternatively use an AtomicInteger to update the goals instead of overwriting the Map value.